# How to show animated image from PNG image using javascript? [ like gmail ]

Tags: javascript, image, animation, png

First of all,check out this image
[image: wink]
Gmail uses this image to display the animated emoticon.
How can we show such animation using a png image?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I leave you a rough [example](http://jsbin.com/otelu) so you can get a starting point:

I will use a simple div element, with the `width` and `height` that the animated image will have, the png sprite as `background-image`  and `background-repeat` set to `no-repeat`

**CSS Needed:**

```
#anim {
  width: 14px; height: 14px;
  background-image: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/im/emotisprites/wink2.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

**Markup needed:**

```
<div id="anim"></div>
```

The trick is basically to scroll the background image sprite up, using the `background-position` CSS property.

We need to know the `height` of the animated image (to know how much we will scroll up each time) and how many times to scroll (how many *frames* will have the animation).

**JavaScript implementation:**

```
var scrollUp = (function () {
  var timerId; // stored timer in case you want to use clearInterval later

  return function (height, times, element) {
    var i = 0; // a simple counter
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
      if (i > times) // if the last frame is reached, set counter to zero
        i = 0;
      element.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + i * height + 'px'; //scroll up
      i++;
    }, 100); // every 100 milliseconds
  };
})();

// start animation:
scrollUp(14, 42, document.getElementById('anim'))
```

**EDIT:** You can also set the CSS properties programmatically so you don't have to define any style on your page, and make a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function) from the above example, that will allow you to show multiple sprite animations simultaneously:

**Usage:**

```
var wink = new SpriteAnim({
  width: 14,
  height: 14,
  frames: 42,
  sprite: "https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/im/emotisprites/wink2.png",
  elementId : "anim1"
});

var monkey = new SpriteAnim({
  width: 18,
  height: 14,
  frames: 90,
  sprite: "https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/im/emotisprites/monkey1.png",
  elementId : "anim4"
});
```

**Implementation:**

```
function SpriteAnim (options) {
  var timerId, i = 0,
      element = document.getElementById(options.elementId);

  element.style.width = options.width + "px";
  element.style.height = options.height + "px";
  element.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + options.sprite + ")";

  timerId = setInterval(function () {
    if (i >= options.frames) {
      i = 0;
    }
    element.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + i * options.height + "px";
     i++;
  }, 100);

  this.stopAnimation = function () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  };
}
```

Notice that I added a `stopAnimation` method, so you can later stop a specified animation just by calling it, for example:

```
monkey.stopAnimation();
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/ifaci).

Comment: +1 For one of the most indepth responses to a fairly simple question

Comment: Great answer, great implementation. As a site note: if your animation stuff is getting more complex: http://www.spritely.net seems to be a nice and small lib for all things related to sprite animation.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I don't understand the use of the two anonymous functions in the first example (why "return function" ?).

Comment: Image location has changed, new image url http://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/im/emotisprites/wink2.png

Comment: I would just like to add that it is also possible to use this technique without JS for simple animations using the steps() funciton in CSS: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this:
http://www.otanistudio.com/swt/sprite_explosions/
and http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites
The answer lies within.

Answer (score 3):

CMS's answer is fine, but there's also the [APNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) (animated PNG) format that you may want to use instead. Of course the first frame (the one displayed even by browsers that don't support APNG) should be the "ending" frame and just specify to skip the first frame in the file.

Comment: good to know about the new format. But i just wanted to know how can we show the animation using static PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Set the background image of an element to the first image, then use javascript to change the image by altering the style every x milliseconds.

Comment: please tell me how to do that. `change the image every x milli`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with TweenMax and steppedEase easing : http://codepen.io/burnandbass/pen/FfeAa    or http://codepen.io/burnandbass/pen/qAhpj  whatever you choose :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS @keyframes can be used in this case

```
@keyframes smile {
    0% { background-postiion: 0 -16px;}
    5% { background-postiion: 0 -32px;}
    10% { background-postiion: 0 -48px;}
    /*...etc*/
}
```

Comment: I've thought of that, do you think it may show some glitch? like half of the first image and half of the second image?