# loading animated png

Tags: png, loading, transparent

I'm looking for an animated Loading icon that is also transparent; however (I know I'm lazy) I dont want to make my own.  Please forgive me if this is not the correct forum for this post, I've just had so much luck here in the past.  does anyone know where I can find one of these....it needs to be very small (icon size).

Comment: http://devthought.com/wp-content/projects/mootools/APNG/Demo/

Comment: http://www.chimply.com is also a good place to get loading animations and has advanced options to customize speed , size etc.

Comment: Use http://preloaders.net/ . Its great!

Comment: I think it's only fair to point out CSS3 as the modern alternative to gifs - http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp - which would also allow the animation of pngs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://www.ajaxload.info/ is your friend.

However, there are no "animated pngs" simply because no browser supports animated pngs.

Comment: Wow very cool website - you win!

Comment: That's not absolutely correct, every Gecko-Browser and Opera do support it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG#Application_support

Comment: jQuery Mobile comes standard with an animated png.

Answer (score 5):

There is a new website http://preloaders.net/ that generates loader icon.
It is a great tool and provides much more customization options as compared to http://www.ajaxload.info/.

http://www.chimply.com/Generator also has many options but I don't like its image quality and it does not provide downloading in `.png` format.

http://www.ajaxload.info/ is good, simple and has remained useful since many years. But, http://preloaders.net/ is just great!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're after generating an [MNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-image_Network_Graphics) file, but I don't know what the state of browser support for them is.

Answer (score 0):

`www.images.google.com`... use the advanced options to specify file format, size etc. –

Comment: using that I cannot specify gif and png... only one or the other

Answer (score 0):

You can transform any GIF animation to a PNG tile set with this convenient tool: http://labs.andregil.net/Gif2TileSet/Gif2TileSet.html

You can then animate it as a background image viewed through a "porthole" by changing the background image's position. It's explained here [How to show animated image from PNG image using javascript? [ like gmail ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736922/how-to-show-animated-image-from-png-image-using-javascript-like-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

There exist a jquery plugin to create animated png its called : animated png :-)  http://animatedpng.info/