# Make a loading icon with static PNG

Tags: javascript, html, css, png

I was planning to make a loading icon with PNG on HTML using Javascript..
What i mean, is not embedding a GIF..

I found [loading animated png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820011/loading-animated-png/) but it refering to http://www.ajaxload.info/
It using GIF..

I got this idea when once, GMail using this method, I inspect-element it..
It using a PNG with about 10 gear-like inside the image..
Each other are the same gear but with some degree of rotation difference..

When the chat is sending, it show a loading icon, the gear, but it was a single gear that moving, rotating...

I wonder how to do this..
I really want to avoid using GIF at all..

***EDIT:***

I got what i want at http://devthought.com/wp-content/projects/mootools/APNG/Demo/
At "Pre-existing DIV element (single image), with per-frame intervals" section..
thanks for the answers

Comment: Ryan's answer is great. I will recommend you to take a look on CSS3 loading animations. Yes, this works only for modern browsers, but that is future :)

Comment: Don't use APGN, that's not standard PNG and its supported is limited. There is no standard animated PNG. Either use animated GIF, or pseudo-animate a set of PNG "frames" with Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As it's now 2022 I'll change to: CSS3 Animations** with an example found here: https://flaviocopes.com/rotate-image/ and the code provided below.

```css
.rotate {
  animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />

<img src="https://i.imgur.com/kDDFvUp.png" class="rotate" width="100" height="100" />
```

**Original Post**

You could use [JQuery Rotate](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate), this would allow you to rotate your PNG image on the page to emulate the loading rotation that you get with a animated GIF.