# How to use putImageData with animated gifs using HTML5 canvas and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gif, animated

I want to manipulate the image data of every frame of an animated gif as it plays in the browser, and I want to do it using HTML5 canvas and Javascript.  For example, I have an animated gif, and I want to convert every frame to grayscale as it plays in the browser.  Is this possible?  Whenever I manipulate the image data in an animated gif, only the first frame is shown (correctly manipulated) and the gif won't play any further.  This would be a very useful technique if there was a solution for this.  Thank you.

EDIT:  Is there a way to query the current frame of an animated gif in Javascript, so I can just use putImageData into the image as the animation progresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this page](http://ernestdelgado.com/public-tests/gifoncanvas/) points out, you can use drawImage() to draw the GIF on the canvas, and at the moment it'll draw the current frame from the GIF in Gecko and WebKit -- but not in Opera, and also not according to the spec, so it's not a good idea to rely on this behavior. As far as I know there's no way to get individual frame data from the DOM; I looked into this for a while before writing [jsgif](http://slbkbs.org/jsgif) (which was mentioned in another answer, but isn't really meant for any sort of practical use as it is -- it's very inefficient, for one).

If you can get away with unpacking the frames on the server and then animating them manually (e.g. like [Gmail does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736922/how-to-show-animated-image-from-png-image-using-javascript-like-gmail)), that might be your best option.

Comment: The first page you linked is really useful and insightful.  I actually was able to convert the canvas images that were based on their respective original images to grayscale easily, and they retain their animations, which is exactly what I was looking for.  Opera renders some of them correctly, others not so well; I'll have to be mindful of the spec when I try this out. Thanks!