# Animated image (e.g. non-GIF) with JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had been trying to animate a .png file with JavaScript while following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736922/how-to-show-animated-image-from-png-image-using-javascript-like-gmail) method. This is the [.png file](http://i1243.photobucket.com/albums/gg555/Nyanja/logoCquake.png) that I want to animate. I want the animated logo to be right by "Cupquake," but the logo doesn't even show up, let alone animate. However, changing "span class=logoCquake" in HTML to a div class displays the logo, but it is below the text.
My JavaScript file:

```
var scrollUp = (function () {
  var timerId;

  return function (height, times, element) {
    var i = 0;
    timerId = setInterval(function () {
      if (i > times)
        i = 0;
      element.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + i * height + 'px';
      i++;
    }, 100);
  };
})();

scrollUp(130, 30, document.getElementByClass('logoCquake'))
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
    <script src="../scripts/logoCquake.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Cupquake - Home</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="topbar">
            <div class="mCquake">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span class="ninja">Ninja</span><span class="cupquake">Cupquake</span><span class="logoCquake"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: typo_semib;
    src: url('fonts/typo_semib.ttf');
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: typo_light;
    src: url('fonts/typo_light.ttf');
}
.wrapper .header
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,#ffa200), color-stop(100%,#d25400));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffa200',endColorstr='#d25400',GradientType=0);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#ffa200,#d25400);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#ffa200,#d25400);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper .header .topbar
{
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(../imgz/head/hBarSBg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.wrapper .header .topbar .mCquake
{
    height: 37px;
    width: 278px;
    background-image: url(../imgz/head/mCqRight.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: none;
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 11.5px;
    margin-bottom: 11.5px;
}
.wrapper .header .ninja
{
    font-family: typo_semib;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #303030;
    margin-left: 55px;
}
.wrapper .header .cupquake
{
    font-family: typo_light;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: #303030;
}
.wrapper .header .logoCquake
{
    height: 112px;
    width: 130px;
    background-image: url(../imgz/logo/logoCquake.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**EDIT:**

---

Tried again, but with the second method listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736922/how-to-show-animated-image-from-png-image-using-javascript-like-gmail), still nothing. These are my current HTML and JS codes:

JS:

```
function SpriteAnim (options) {
  var timerId,
      i = 0,
      element = document.getElementByClass(options.elementClass);

  element.style.width = options.width + "px";
  element.style.height = options.height + "px";
  element.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  element.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + options.sprite + ")";

  timerId = setInterval(function () {
    if (i >= options.frames) {
      i = 0;
    }
    element.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + i * options.height + "px";
     i ++;
  }, 100);

  this.stopAnimation = function () {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  };
}

var cupcake = new SpriteAnim({
  width: 130,
  height: 112,
  frames: 30,
  sprite: "..\imgz\logo\logoCquake.png",
  elementClass : "logoCquake"
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
    <script language="javascript" src="SpriteAnim.js">
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Cupquake - Home</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="mCquake">
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="ninja">Ninja </span><span class="cupquake">Cupquake</span><span class="logoCquake"></span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my code seems to work:

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
div{background:url(http://i1243.photobucket.com/albums/gg555/Nyanja/logoCquake.png);height:33px;width:39px}
</style>
<div id=anim></div>
<script>
var i=0;
setInterval(function(){i+=33.6;document.getElementById("anim").style.backgroundPosition="0px "+i+"px"},100)
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d9BhN/ here it is working. Id say go with Will's way so much less coding. +1 Will thanks for the code. Its perfect.

Comment: Alright, I'll just stick with that instead, thanks. @John Riselvato

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'span' tag being an inline element it either needs a 'display: block' property or 'float: left', i tried your code and it worked for me after i added 'display: block' to the 'span' tag with class 'logoCquake'. Hope this helps you.

Note: if you use 'display: block' the span will move to new line and if you use 'float: left' the 'span' tag will move to the left of the text.