# website intro animation made of images JS

Tags: javascript, html, animation

So I have 6 png-s which I would like to compile into intro animation for website. It sholud start automatically and after it is finished take us to index page.
I want it to work on all devices. I suppose it could be done with JS so do you know any good tutorial couse i cant seem to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736922/how-to-show-animated-image-from-png-image-using-javascript-like-gmail

Comment: It completely depends on what you want. I'd suggest you read up on web animations: http://www.howstuffworks.com/web-animation.htm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery...

```
1) pre-load the images
2) Create a div on the page
3) create a function, call it once
4) in the function, update the content of the div with the next image, update a variable (to tell what image is next) and call the function from within itself with setTimeout()
5) Once all images have been shown, direct the user to some page via document.location = "http://....."
```

Since all images are pre-loaded, it should run smooth.
gl

Edit: or create a gif, and redirect the users after X seconds...